# Using a "shortcut" function gives me a "Illegal invocation” error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I'm having this code in Javascript ES6:

```
// Create a new object
var foo = new A();

// Create shortcuts to use localStorage faster
foo.set = window.localStorage.setItem;
foo.get = window.localStorage.getItem;

// Try to use localStorage 
foo.set('count', 1);
```

But I get "Illegal invocation” for the last line, and I don't understand why.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You are changing the context (`this`) of the function.

Answer (score 8):

You are changing the methods context of this. Use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set `this` to `localStorage`:

```
var foo = {};
undefined
foo.set = window.localStorage.setItem.bind(localStorage);
foo.get = window.localStorage.getItem.bind(localStorage);

// Try to use localStorage
foo.set('count', 1);
console.log(foo.get('count'));
```

Alternatively you can create a wrapper function that invokes the localStorage functions.

```
foo.set = (k,v) => window.localStorage.setItem(k,v)
foo.get = (k) => window.localStorage.getItem(k)
```